# Infinite games and pay-off functions

Tags: game-theory

I'm asked to prove that, in a version of the [Gale-Stewart game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem#Gale.E2.80.93Stewart_games) where the two players alternately pick zero or one, the pay-off function cannot be continuous. From what i have read, the pay-off function H, typically, assigns the value 1 when the play (sequence of choices) is in the pay-off set A, in which case player 1 wins, and the value 0 when the play is not in A, in which case player 2 wins.

First question: H takes finite sequences, the play/sequence obtained at the point in the game where H is applied, as an argument, right?

Second question/claim: It seems rather obvious that H is not continuous, since its value is either 0 or 1 and it cannot change from one to the other continuously (it reminds me of discrete metric spaces, though they might not be relevant at all). I'm having a bit trouble accepting that it really is that simple, though, so a more formal argument or proof (sketch) would be much appreciated.

(If it is not true that the pay-off function is not continuous, then please say so)

Comment: You could have the pay-off set be the entire real unit interval (i.e player 1 always wins or loses), and the pay-off function is continuous (in fact constant). But otherwise, you're looking a mapping a connected interval onto 2 discrete points, hence it can't be continuous.

Comment: The payoff function is not defined on finite sequences, only on infinte sequences- the ultimate plays or outcomes.

Comment: @user14111 The comment is not directed to you. It is a response to Eman writing "First question: H takes finite sequences, the play/sequence obtained at the point in the game where H is applied, as an argument, right?".

Comment: @user14111 No problem, and don't talk yourself down.

Comment: Thanks for the respons, everbody. Seems rather obvious now that the payoff function, of course, must be defined on infinite sequences. @MichaelGreinecker: Any thoughts on how to proof that no conitnuous function deciding the winner exists? (There is suppose to be a theorem stating this. To me it seems rather trivial, if the payoff function always maps into 0 or 1, but it could be I have mistunderstod something)

Comment: @Eman: How is the space of plays topologized? This will determine which payoff functions are continuus.

Comment: @Eman: If the topology doesn't make the space connected (and the product topology does not), the payoff functions might well be continuous.

Comment: @Eman: in the wikipedia article you quoted, the topology is defined.